# loop to copy and paste always one row below

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching an efficient way to copy data from one spreadsheet to another and always paste one row below. Someone helped me with this code, but unfortunately it is not working for the columns i need. So I need to copy data from E2:P2 on sheet "Dividends" and paste firstly on C11:N11, then tomorrow if I run again should paste on C12:N12 and always one row below... When I run the code, it pastes the data on C111:N111, and if I run again still paste on the same range, so does not work for me. I would appreciate your help.

```
Sub Copy_range()

    ' edit line below to change where data will be copied from
    Worksheets("Dividends").Range("E2:P2").Copy ' copy the value

    ' select the first cell on the "Draft" sheet
    Worksheets("Draft").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("C11").Select

    Dim count As Integer
    count = 1

    'skip all used cells
    Do While Not (ActiveCell.value = None)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("C11").Select
        count = count + 1

    Loop

    
    Worksheets("Draft").Range("C11" & count & ":N11" & count).PasteSpecial ' paste the value
  

End Sub
```

Comment: Somewhere in your spreadsheet, you will need to retain the context of where you last pasted that row.  This has to be in the Excel spreadsheet, because VBA itself does not have it's own persistent storage (persistent = "will survive closing and reopening the spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveCell and Offset can often lead to unexpected results and makes the code hard to read. You can have the counting loop working without all of this, by simply going through column C cells starting at C11 and looking for empty one.

One of possible ways is

```
    Sub Copy_range
      Dim count As Integer
      count = 11
      Do While Worksheets("Draft").Range("C" & count).Value <> ""
      '<>"" means "is not empty", as long as this happens we go down looking for empty cell
        count = count + 1
      Loop
      'Now count is row with first empty cell outside of top 10 rows in column C

      Worksheets("Dividends").Range("E2:P2").Copy
      Worksheets("Draft").Range("C" & count).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you could most likely just solve this with a `Vlookup Formula` autofilled to the target area. But the below code should do it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub moveDividends()

Dim wsF As Worksheet 'From
Dim wsD As Worksheet 'Destination
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wsF = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With wsD
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).row
        Else
            LastRow = 1
        End If
    End With

    With wsD
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "C").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 5).Value
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "D").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 6).Value
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "E").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 7).Value
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "F").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 8).Value
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "G").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 9).Value
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "H").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 10).Value
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "I").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 11).Value
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "J").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 12).Value
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "K").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 13).Value
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "L").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 14).Value
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "M").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 15).Value
            wsD.Cells(LastRow, "N").Value = wsF.Cells(2, 16).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

all method are rigth, or simply use:

```
Sub Copy_range()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    ' edit line below to change where data will be copied from
    Worksheets("Dividends").Range("E2:P2").Copy ' copy the value
    ' find the 1th not-used rows
    lastRow = Worksheets("Draft").Cells(1048576, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    lastRow = IIf(lastrows < 11, 11, lastrows) 'optional if is possible that the rows 10, 9, 8,.... are empty
    Worksheets("Draft").Range("C" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' paste the value
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the below

```
Sub Copy_range()
    ' edit line below to change where data will be copied from
    Worksheets("Dividends").Range("E2:P2").Copy ' copy the value

    'count cells and add 1 for next row
    last_row = Worksheets("Draft").Range("C" & Worksheets("Draft").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If last_row > 1000000 Then last_row = 1

    Worksheets("Draft").Range("C" & last_row ).PasteSpecial 
    ' paste the value only need to ref first cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Had a small bug which I have just fixed.

Comment: That did not work for what i need. I need to start always on C11:N11, then paste always one row below.. I am doing this for many columns in my spreadhseet, so it is not necessarily the last row

Comment: Ok, but it is pasting on C2:N2 in spreadsheet draft, can you edit in order to paste on C11:N11?

Comment: I will have a look at this shortly.